# Isomorphic quotients of a countably infinitely-generated free abelian group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-space

Let $F$ denote the free abelian group on countably infinite generators. I am trying to understand the relationship between normal subgroups $A$ and $B$ of $F$ with isomorphic quotients. So is there a characterization of
$$F/A\cong F/B$$
in terms of $A$ andf $B$? I know that there is no easy characterization of this, for example
$$A\cong B \nRightarrow F/A\cong F/B$$
and the converse implication is also clearly not true. Still, there should be some necessary or sufficient conditions on $A$ and $B$ that are easier to express. Is there anything at all that can be said about this equivalence relation on the set of normal subgroups of $F$? Is there any partial answers to this question under some restrictions on $A$ and $B$ for example? If you could refer me to a source it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It is very unclear what kind of a nontautological answer you expect in this generality. For finitely presented groups you have Tietze's theorem.